# Rodar código python através de batch no cmd da anaconda

Tags: python, batch, anaconda

Tenho um batch criado para rodar um arquivo python, mas ele está abrindo o cmd do windows e como o python esta instalado no anaconda, não funciona, teria como rodar direto do cmd do anaconda como administrador?

> start Python c:\scrapy\cpfl selenium\cpfl.py

Answer (score -1):

Boa noite, o que resolveria o seu problema seria adicionar a instalação atual do Python (Diretório onde ele está instalado no HD) as variáveis de ambiente do Windows.

Assim você vai poder executar programas no cmd:

py seuprograma.py

## Mas como fazer isso?

Caso não consiga achar onde o Python do Anaconda Navigator está instalado, recomendo baixar a versão .exe do syte do python.

Aqui está um tutorial de como adicionar o Python ao PATH(Variáveis de ambiente).
https://python.org.br/instalacao-windows/

Espero ter ajudado. Boa sorte!

Comment: Nao deu certo, ele não reconhece